# general solution of $y''(x)+y(x)=\frac{1}{1+(sinx)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've found the solution of $y''(x)+y(x)=0$ : $y(x)=c_1 cosx+c_2sinx$ but for the general integral?

Comment: Have you tried variation of parameters?

Comment: I've found $c_1(x)=arctan(sinx)$ but for $c_2(x)$ I've problem

Comment: Expand $\frac{1}{1+\sin^2 x}$ as a Fourier cosine series and use the superposition principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose: $y(x) = (\cos x) u(x)$

$y' = -\sin x u + cos x u'\\
y'' = -\cos x u - 2 \sin x u' + \cos x u''$

$\cos x u'' - 2\sin x u' = \frac {1}{1+\sin^2x}\\
\cos^2 x u'' - 2\sin x \cos x u' = \frac {\cos x}{1 +\sin^2x}\\
\cos^2 x u' = \int \frac {\cos x}{1 +\sin^2x} dx\\
\cos^2 x u' = \tan^{-1} (\sin x)$

We can ignore the arbitrary constants.  If we bring them along for the ride they will equal C cos x + D sin x.

$u' = \sec^2 x \tan^{-1} (\sin x)\\
u = \int \sec^2 x \tan^{-1} (\sin x) dx\\
y = \cos x \int \sec^2 x \tan^{-1} (\sin x) dx$

integration by parts
$u = \tan^{-1} (\sin x), dv = \sec^2 x dx\\
du = \frac {\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}, v = \tan x$

$\tan x \tan^{-1}(\sin x) - $$\int \frac{\sin x}{1 + \sin^2 x} dx\\
\int \frac{\sin x}{2 - \cos^2 x}\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt2 + i \cos x} + \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt2 - i \cos x} dx\\
i \ln (1+i\cos x) - i \ln (1-i \cos x)$

$y = C_1 \cos x + C_2 \sin x + \sin x \tan^{-1}(\sin x) - i\frac{\sqrt 2}4 \cos x \ln(1+i\cos x) + i \frac{\sqrt 2}4\cos x \ln(1-i \cos x)$

It can probably be simplified farther, but I will leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

By expanding $\frac{1}{1+\sin^2(x)}$ as:
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n}\cos(2nx) \tag{1}$$
and exploiting the fact that the particular solution of
$$ y''(x)+y(x) = \cos(2nx) \tag{2} $$
is given by $-\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}$, we get:
$$ y(x) = c_1\cos(x)+c_2 \sin(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n}}{4n^2-1}\cos(2nx) \tag{3} $$
or, by writing $\cos(2nx)$ as $\text{Re}(e^{2n ix})$ and computing the resulting series:

> $$\small y(x) = c_1\cos(x)+c_2 \sin(x)+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\,\text{Re}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^2 e^{2ix}-1}{2(\sqrt{2}-1)e^{ix}}\cdot\text{arctanh}((\sqrt{2}-1)e^{ix})\right).\tag{4} $$